# Typescript: How remove last item from array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array :

```
["one-", "two-", "three-", "testing-"]
```

After converted into string

```
"one-,two-,three-,testing-"
```

How to remove last charecter hypen(-) after testing and how should i get new array.

Accepted output

```
["one-", "two-", "three-", "testing"]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an elegant solution use `.slice(0, -1)` for the string:

```
let newString = "one-,two-,three-,testing-".slice(0, -1); // "one-,two-,three-,testing"
```

To get the new array, simply use `.split(',')`:

```
let newArray = newString.split(','); // ["one-", "two-", "three-", "testing"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var str = "one-,two-,three-,testing-";
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
```

to take the last character off of your string. Then, to make it into a list:

```
var newList = str.split(“,”);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = ["one-", "two-", "three-", "testing-"];
let DataStr = array.toString();
let OutputStr = DataStr.replace("-", "");
var res = OutputStr.split(",");
console.log(res);
```

try this